# Identify if a date range includes Weekends and/or Holidays in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-dates

I'm trying to figure out how to identify if a date range contains weekends or holidays.  For example:

| Name | Start Date | End Date | Check |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Aug 22, 2023 | Aug 26, 2023 |  |
| Jane | Jul 1, 2023 | Jul 8, 2023 |  |
| Bill | Aug 28, 2023 | Aug 30, 2023 |  |
| Bob | Sep 18, 2023 | Sep 22, 2023 |  |
| Tim | Dec 25, 2023 | Dec 28, 2023 |  |
| Tom | Feb 27, 2024 | Mar 1, 2024 |  |
| Dan | Feb 28, 2024 | Mar 3, 2024 |  |

In this case, I would want to know that the rows John, Jane, Tim, and Dan all have dates that include weekends.  In the check field, ideally it would say Pass or Fail depending if the date includes weekends and/or holidays or not.

I've tried the WORKDAY function but can't get it to consider the holidays.

```
=IF( WORKDAY(B2, (C2-B2), H2:H11)=C2, "Pass", "Fail")
```

I used `H2:H11` as a list of holiday dates.  Not sure if I'm listing them correctly.  Can anyone help here?  Also, how do I hard code dates as serial values instead of referring to the `H2:H11` range?

Also, I want to make sure if the start date or end date is a holiday/weekend, it also marks as Fail.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: The end date for the last two are past dates is it possible or is it a typo

Comment: sorry that was a typo, should be 2024

Comment: Look into NETWORKDAYS() this allows you to add a range of holidays to exclude them in the count. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/networkdays-function-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7

Comment: `=IF(NETWORKDAYS(B2,C2,H2:H6)=C2-B2,"pass","fail")`

Comment: There was one more typo, in formula it was showing HolList as `H2:H6` while in notes it was `H2:H11`, fixed it.

Comment: Referring to range will be more dynamic rather than hard coding the holiday list, so it gives you room to expand and collapse, i would have converted the range into a `Table`

Comment: How do I include the start date in the formula as well?  For example, the row with Tim is pass even though it starts on Christmas

Comment: Copy the formula posted by @ScottCraner sir as is and paste in cell `D2` provided the cell is in edit mode and then use fill handle to fill down